# Junit - method at the end of each test

Tags: java, junit

I got a method that I call at the end of every test to reset the streams positions.

```
Test{
[....]
reset();
}
```

Is there any elegant way to avoid such a repetition?

Comment: have you ever heard of setUp() or tearDown()? with @Before and @After?

Comment: yes, I use setup but I don't see how to use in this case. Is setup invoked every time a test is executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) annotaton, that goes with JUnit.
Example from source:

```
 public class Example {
    File output;
    @Before public void createOutputFile() {
          output= new File(...);
    }
    @Test public void something() {
          ...
    }
    @After public void deleteOutputFile() {
          output.delete();
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

the other answers suggest the `@After` annotation on a public method (preferably with name `teardown`) which is technically right and a good answer to your question.

But essential properties of unittests is that they need to be fast and independent of each other.

Therefore the better approach is to use a fresh mock of the stream with every test. This is best done by using a mocking framework like Mockito, JMock or alike.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, create new method with [@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the @After annotation - indicates something needs to be done at the end of each method run.

Answer (score 0):

Use `@After` annotation.

```
@Test 
public void testSomething() {
   // test goes here
}

@After 
public void doSomethingAfterTest() {
   // reset
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are the @s: [Before](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Before.html) and [After](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/After.html). Class instance methods with these annotations will run before/after every test case.

There is also [BeforeClass](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) and [AfterClass](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/AfterClass.html), which I didn't see anyone point out yet. These @s may be put onto static methods of your class, and those methods will execute before and after *all* of the tests in your class have completed. It is handy in certain situations.